When creating model to use for Rest Assured and Java does the getter function name matter?
Context
I'm trying to learn about api testing with RestAssured and Java for a Client (haven't used java in years). I have a ApiTest class with a create function to pass a product as the body to post to my xampp server. I get a message
{
    "message": "Unable to create product. Data is incomplete."
}

When the getter for category_id is named getCategoryId.
It will work and create and add the product if the getter function for category_id is named getCategory_id
Question
Why would the name of the getter function cause an issue?
package testing;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import io.restassured.response.ValidatableResponse;
import models.Product;
import models.ProductTwo;

public class ApiTest {

    @Test
    public void createSerializedProduct(){
        String endpoint = "http://localhost:80/api_testing/product/create.php";
        Product product = new Product(
               "Water Bottle",
               "Blue water bottle. Holds 64 ounces",
               12,
               3

        );
        var response = given().body(product).when().post(endpoint).then();
        response.log().body();
    }
}

package models;

public class Product {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private double price;
    private int category_id;

    public Product(){}

    public Product(String name, String description, double price, int category_id) {
        setName(name);
        setDescription(description);
        setPrice(price);
        setCategoryId(category_id);
    }

    //use for put requests
    public Product(int id, String name, String description, double price, int category_id) {
        setId(id);
        setName(name);
        setDescription(description);
        setPrice(price);
        setCategoryId(category_id);    
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getCategoryId() {
        return category_id;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(int category_id) {
        this.category_id = category_id;
    }
}

Solution to fix the issue is to change getCategoryId to getCategory_id
I just don't know why that causes an issue and don't want to make the same mistake in the future

I don't know of rest assured, but most json parsers by default use getters and setters to resolve properties - jackson, one of the most used parsers is one such example. Rest assured definitely depends on such parser, so check the documentation for information how to configure it. It should either specify the parser, in which case you can use its documentation, and use the parsers API, or it should have its own API for such configurations.

Note that the usual Java naming convention would be to use lower camel case for both field name and method name (categoryId, getCategoryId()).  Snake case is unusual in Java sources.  I anticipate that if you switched the field to lower camel then the getter could be lower camel too (and probably would need to be).

I'm not familiar with your technology stack, but chances are that it is mapping names of API parameters to names of accessors according to JavaBeans rules.  If the API uses the name category_id, then according to JavaBeans, which doesn't attribute special significance to underscores,  that maps to getCategory_id().  If you use a different name then the model class does not correspond properly to the API.

@JohnBollinger your correct as the column name in the DB is category_id so I believe restassured requires the exact same name for the request to be correct.
